# Logout when using cookies

Tags: php, cookies, logout

I am beginner in using php cookies and I am trying to make a simple login and logout form using cookies. everything was good but when I press logout link I can't logout. and to logout I have to delete the cookies from the browser.

log_in page

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE["Email"])){
    header("location: home.php");    
}
?>


<form method="post" action="log_in.php">   
<font size="6">Sign In</font>

Email Address: </b></font><input type="text" name="Email" id="email"  />  

password:  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  />    

<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="1" id="check"/> Remember Me

<input type="submit" name="Login" id="sign" value="sign in" >

<?php 
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
    $user_email = $_POST['Email'];  
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $check_user = "SELECT * FROM user where user_email  = '$user_email' AND user_pass = '$password'";
    $run = mysql_query($check_user );

    if (mysql_num_rows($run) > 0){
        $_SESSION['Email']= $user_email;   

        $_SESSION['start'] = time(); 
        if(isset($_POST['rememberMe'])){
            $expire=time()+120;
            setcookie("Email", "Email", $expire);
        }
    else{
        $expire=time()+30;
        setcookie("Email", "Email", $expire);
    }
    echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";   
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('email or password incorrect!')</script>";     
}}
?>
```

home page

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["Email"])){
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["Email"] . "!<br>";
    echo '<a href="logoutForm.php">logout</a>';
}
else{
    $now = time(); // Checking the time now when home page starts.
    if ($now > $expire) {
        session_destroy();
        header("location: log_in.php");    
}}
```

logout page

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION['Email']);
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: log_in.php");

 if(isset($_SESSION['Email'])):
     setcookie($_SESSION['Email'],'',time()-7000000,'/');
 endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: You seem to only be unsetting your Email session variable. You're also using `$_SESSION['start']` so that stands at still being set. You can try `unset($_SESSION);` to unset all session variables.

Comment: Your home page doesn't have `session_start();` least not in what you posted; it's required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your home page (code) doesn't have `session_start();` least not in what you posted; it's required when using [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php); it doesn't work on its own.

Give this a go:

***Sidenote:*** `$expire` is undefined for `home page` code, so you will need to use the same or similar method as you used for the other pages.

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["Email"])){
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["Email"] . "!<br>";
    echo '<a href="logoutForm.php">logout</a>';
}
else{
    $now = time(); // Checking the time now when home page starts.
    if ($now > $expire) { // $expire is undefined
        session_start(); // <= required
        session_destroy(); // <= does not work on its own
        header("location: log_in.php");    
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding session_start(); in the home page but it didn't work, I think the problem in the logout page.

Comment: Instead of `unset($_SESSION['Email']);` in your logout page; have you tried `unset($_SESSION);`? @user3891365 that will unset all sessions.

Comment: @user3891365 Plus, instead of `setcookie($_SESSION['Email'],'',time()-7000000,'/');` try `setcookie($_COOKIE['Email'],'',time()-7000000,'/');` in your logout page.

Comment: @user3891365 Another thing I spotted; in your home page `$expire` is undefined which is a contributing factor. Add error reporting to the top of that or all file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you will see the error stating as undefined.

Comment: session_start();
setcookie($_COOKIE['Email'],'',time()-7000000,'/');
 unset($_SESSION['Email']);
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: log_in.php");       

I tried this code in logout page but it didn't work

Comment: @user3891365 Did you see my comment just above yours? About `$expire` being undefined in home page. Reload the comments and see. This `if ($now > $expire)` renders to `if ($now > nothing)`

Comment: How did the cookies end up tasting @Fred-ii-? :P

Comment: @Darren Looks like they were sweet in the end!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner What is the  `time()-7000000` for? Why not just `0`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to completely destroy the session, you can just use session_destroy()

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Or if you are just looking to unset the Email, you can use

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['Email']))
  unset($_SESSION['Email']);
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be included when using [`session_destroy();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)